# Want to change date in certain openvz containers on one host

Tags: redhat, timezone-offset, localtime, openvz, zoneinfo

I have a physical server running 5 OpenVZ instances.

I want to be able to time shift one instance running Oracle, but not the physical host.

I have tried creating a zoneinfo file offset by days rather than hours, but it will only accept valid offsets.

Does anyone know of a way I can get just one or two instances ignoring host date and using one well in the past and/or future?

Any assistance much appreciated.

Running RHEL 5.2

I may have to look at an alternative free way of running multiple instances otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time is shared betwenn host and all containers, you can as you found only change the timezone. The only other thing you can do is to allow any container to manage time on the whole server (for host and all containers).

Look for sys_time capability in vzctl: http://openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8